# Graph with onclick event to get x and y-axis value and animate the line towards x and y axis point

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, html5-canvas

I want to make a graph using either html5 or jquery. When an user clicks [touch or mouseclick] on the graph, it should generate a point and get the value of x and y value and from that generated point it should draw a animation line towards x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: maybe flot with the crosshair plugin: http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-flot/tracking-series.html

Comment: Your question is too broad for stack-overflow.